# How can we say our field of study in English?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

For example

> I am learning computer engineering in university.

Is it right to say "I am majoring in computer engineering" or is there more precise term?

Comment: [I am studying CE,not learning]. Please use a capital letter for the pronoun I.

Comment: It is fine. You could also say "My major is computer engineering".

Comment: In UK you might say "I am *reading* computer engineering at X university."

Comment: See my accepted answer to [this question.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245818/how-is-an-academic-course-structured-in-its-content-usa/246210#246210)